# Reuse existing resources as a parameters in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, devops

I want to create cloudfomation template that reuse the existing resources for example I want to create a new instance and attach it to an existing loadbalancer and I want to select the loadbalancer form my existing loadbalancers in a dropdown.

Is there anyway to make cloudformation template to show the existing resource and reuse it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not list the loadbalancer in the dropdown as its not available in AWS-Specific Parameter Types.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types

But you can use aws **Fn::ImportValue** to import existing loadbalancer value.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion , It will be based on the pervious created stacks and I can do this